# Composition function problem. Please explain the answer! $g(x) = 3x^2 +2 $ and $g(f(x)) = x$. What is $f(2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is $f(2)$, given that $g(x) = 3 x^2 +2 $ and $g(f(x)) = x$ ?

The answer is $0$, but I do not understand how to arrive at that answer. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$g(x)=3x^2+2$$ and $$g(f(x))=x$$
 now use f(x) in the equation of g(x) so as to get g(f(x)) and you get:

$$g(f(x))= 3f^2(x) + 2$$
which is equal to $$g(f(x))=x$$ so on equation we get;

$$3f^2(x)+2=x$$
$$f(x)= \sqrt\frac{x-2}{3}$$

when you replace x with 2 you get 0 as the answer, which is here required answer.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation made so much sense.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

We have $g(f(2))=2$ . Since $g(x)=2$ if and only if $x=0$, we can conclude $f(2)=0$

Answer (score 2):

Substituting in, $2 = g(f(2)) = 3f(2)^2+2 \implies 3f(2)^2 = 0 \implies f(2)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$g(f(x))=3(f(x))^2+2$
$x=3(f(x))^2+2$

You can handle from here?